# Script to run a macro at a specific time with excel running in invisible mode

Tags: vb.net

'This code is inside an module of a Workbook.
   Sub Notes_Email_Excel_Cells2()
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
        Dim NSession As Object
        Dim NDatabase As Object
        Dim NUIWorkSpace As Object
        Dim NDoc As Object
        Dim NUIdoc As Object
        Dim WordApp As Object
        Dim subject As String
        Dim dd As String
        Dim stAttachment As String
        Dim obAttachment As Object, EmbedObject As Object
        Const EMBED_ATTACHMENT As Long = 1454
        Dim Wb As Workbook
        Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range
        Dim CC(1)
        CC(1) = "yyy@itc.in,"

```
    If bIsBookOpen("Daily Beetle Count Report - MMGR.xlsx") = True Then
    Set Wb = Workbooks("Daily Beetle Count Report - MMGR.xlsx")
    Else
    Workbooks.Open ("B:\Sangeet\Daily Beetle Count Report - MMGR.xlsx")
    Set Wb = Workbooks("Daily Beetle Count Report - MMGR.xlsx")
    End If

    Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")

    'Next line only works with 5.x and above. Replace password with your password



    subject = "HOT SPOTS Infestation " & Now
    Debug.Print subject


    Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
    Set NDatabase = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")
    If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then NDatabase.OPENMAIL

    'Create a new Lotus Notes document

    Set NDoc = NDatabase.CreateDocument
     stAttachment = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
     Set obAttachment = NDoc.CreateRichTextItem("stAttachment")
     Set EmbedObject = obAttachment.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", stAttachment)

    With NDoc
        .SendTo = "xxx@itc.in"              'CHANGE RECIPIENT EMAIL ADDRESS
        .CopyTo = ""
        .subject = subject

        'Email body text, including marker text which will be replaced by the Excel cells

        .body = "Dear All," & vbLf & vbLf & "Please find the Hotspot areas" & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "**PASTE HERE**" & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Auto Generated Mail. Please Donot Reply."

        .Save True, False
    End With

    'Edit the just-created document to copy and paste the Excel cells into it via Word

    Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.EDITDocument(True, NDoc)
    With NUIdoc

        'Find the marker text in the Body item

        .GotoField ("Body")
        .FINDSTRING "**PASTE HERE**"
        '.DESELECTALL 'Uncomment to leave the marker text in place (cells are inserted immediately before)

        'Copy Excel cells to clipboard
        Wb.Sheets("HOT SPOT").Activate
        Sheets("HOT SPOT").Range("v2:w21").Copy                  'CHANGE SHEET AND RANGE TO BE COPIED AND PASTED

        'Create a temporary Word Document

        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = False                                 'True to aid debugging
        WordApp.Documents.Add

        'Paste into Word document and copy to clipboard

        With WordApp.Selection
            .PasteSpecial DataType:=10      'Enum WdPasteDataType: 10 = HTML; 2 = Text; 1 = RTF
            .WholeStory
            .Copy
        End With


        'Paste from clipboard (Word) to Lotus Notes document

        .Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        WordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=False
        Set WordApp = Nothing

        .Send


        .Close




    End With

    Set NSession = Nothing
    If bIsBookOpen("Daily Beetle Count Report - MMGR.xlsx") Then
    Workbooks("Daily Beetle Count Report - MMGR.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Else
    End If




End Sub
Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: 1) That appears to be VBA code, not VB.NET code. 2) Please format your code better. 3) Do you want to run it on Windows startup *or* at a specific time? 4) I do not know of any way to run Excel without running Excel. 5) Please edit your question to include the question instead of using the title for the question.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here **[ask]** and it's also important to look here .. **[mcve]** .. **Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: You cannot run Excel VBA or automate Excel without starting Excel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions  Andrew, Ken and David. Since  I'm new to community i will try to improve on your mentioned points. Thankyou again..